# Meaning of "It's not in the bag."

Tags: meaning

The Context

> Important rules of job interviews:
>
> A. Repeat to yourself: "It's not in the bag."
>
> B. To answer the question, "What would you do?" think of the correct
>   answer to "What should I do?" and give that as your response.
>
> C. Laugh at their jokes, but don't offer your own.

Comment: [General Reference](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/be-in-the-bag) *If something is **in the bag**, you are **certain to get it** or to achieve it*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that they should not be over-confident; the job isn't theirs yet.

[in the bag](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+bag)  (informal)
if something is in the bag, you are certain to get it or to achieve it

> Once we'd scored the third goal, the match was pretty much *in the bag*.
>   Nobody knows who'll get the job, despite rumors that Keating has it *in the bag*.

[etymology](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/It%27s_in_the_bag_etymology?#slide=2):  c. 16th. century, from the (bird hunting) 'game bag', meaning not only had the game been hit, but also found, retrieved and was now safely and irrevocably on its eventual way to the table.

Comment: Quibble: If it's in the bag, you *have got or achieved it*, rather than "you are certain to get it or to achieve it"

Comment: @andy256 - it can't be in the past tense if you're using it for an imminent achievement, for which this idiom is most commonly used.

Comment: So instead of a quibble, it turns out that I disagree with your answer. If something is in the bag, it has already happened, as explained by the etymology you quote :-)

Comment: @andy256 - I do see your point. You are correct that it is used for something just achieved. But it is used (or perhaps misused?) for anticipated events. Often. Knock on wood. ;)

Comment: A bird in the bag is worth two in the hand.

Comment: Your first sentence bothered me, and a site search led me to [this earlier and as-yet unrecognised answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/77311/2637). What do you think?

Comment: So you agree the usage is at least "awkward"? Do you agree @Kris's analysis in that earlier answer, and if so did you *upvote* it? I think it's disappointing that what looks to me like the only relevant/correct answer there should have been passed over because too many voters are either ignorant or didn't understand the true nature of the question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I had not even read the question, much less all the answers to upvote anything whatsoever. You've lost me. Not truly interested in going through that entire thread just to upvote one poor soul. I wasn't even a member here in August when that was posted.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess we just have different perspectives. I'm not truly interested in answering trivial GR questions like this one - at most I just post a link to a definition while I'm closevoting. But I *am* interested in subtle aspects of "acceptable" usage that might flummox even competent native speakers.

Answer (score 1):

Just means that there is no certainty that the desired outcome is achieved.

Comment: Right, but always show the source of your information.