# One doesn't know about his/their future

Tags: grammar

Which one is more appropriate? "He" Or "Their?"

Comment: You should provide some context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using both “one’s” and “their” to refer to the same entity](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77308/using-both-one-s-and-their-to-refer-to-the-same-entity)

Answer (score 3):

Neither.

> **One** doesn’t know about **one’s** future

(Likewise: he/his, they/their. Keep to the same person.)